# Is there built in support to increment an attribute by x

Tags: javascript, dojo

When we set animateProperty in dojo, can we do this

```
dojo.animateProperty({
  node:byId("ss"),
  property: { left: "+=100" }
});
```

How can this be made. Want to move the container 100px to the RIGHT ... from the current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dojox.fx](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/fx) have a lot of extra animations that some people often use. If you want to slide a node relative from its current position you can use `dojox.fx.slideBy()`. A complete example with loading the class and waiting for dom-ready event.

```
dojo.require("dojox.fx");
dojo.ready(function(){
    dojox.fx.slideBy({
        node:     dojo.byId('slide'),
        duration: 2000,
        top:      100,
        left:     -50
    }).play();
});
```

This will slide the node with id `slide` 100px down, and 50px to the left.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in support for this, so you'll have to manually get the original position first.

```
dojo.animateProperty({
    node: "ss",
    properties: {
         left: function(node){
             return node.style.offsetLeft + 100;
         }
    }
});
```

[Here's a thread in the Dojo forums about it.](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/animation-relative-units-td871822.html)

Answer (score 0):

onAnimate callback can be right place where we can determine the current style property value, instead of getting the style property value from node.